How to design APIs that listen to the input device data, and dispatch corresponding events when a user actions happend in c#
I’m new to .NET and WPF, and I’m currently working on a project that involves mapping joystick input to system actions in a WPF application using SharpDX.DirectInput. Specifically, I want to design an event system that detects when the joystick is manipulated by the user and triggers corresponding events so that I can implement my code during a callback.
The solution I’ve come across involves actively using an infinite while loop to continuously retrieve joystick states. However, this approach is quite costly in terms of CPU usage, as it keeps the loop running all the time. It seems there isn't a straightforward “joystick state changed” event, since the angle of the stick is always changing (based on its sensitivity) so that games tend to poll the joystick sensors all the time.
To implement an API similar to what I’ve described, do I need to create a background thread that listens to the input device data all the time? And when the data frame differs from the previous frame within a specific time window, I start dispatching events (invoking callbacks).
For Example:
Callback interface
interface IJoystickEvent
{
    void onStatusChanged(EventArgs e);

    void onPull(EventArgs e);

    void onButtonClick(EventArgs e);

    ...
}

Customize implementation of a event
class JoystickEvent: IJoystickEvent
{
    void onStatusChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void onPull(EventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void onButtonClick(EventArgs e) { }
}


A thread running background that listen to the input device, but I force a 100ms sleep here so it doesn't constantly occupy the CPU.
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    JoystickEvent joystickEvent = new JoystickEvent();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Task.Run(() => {
            while (true)
            {
                var datas = joystick.GetBufferedData();
                switch (datas)
                {
                    case "Pull":
                        joystickEvent.onPull(...);
                        break;
                    case "Button Click":
                        joystickEvent.onButtonClick(...);
                        break;
                }
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
        });
    }

Is this a reasonable design?
Any insights or guidance on the best approach for achieving this in a WPF application would be greatly appreciated!

Since you're new to WPF, you should consider UWP and the Windows.Gaming.Input namespace to satisfy your needs. UWP is very similar to WPF. Which "is" Win2 (via a using); which is similar to Win3.
